# Exec dynamic PowerShell script on all except those in a list

Tags: powershell

I'd like to create a whitelist of wlan profiles that I *don't* want to delete...

`$whitelist = "mywifi1", "mywifi2", "mywifi3"`

And then iterate all of my wlan profiles using...

`netsh wlan show profiles`

And execute the following on all of those *except* the ones in my whitelist...

`netsh wlan delete profile name="@"

Where @ is the name of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there is a way to do that without some string manipulations, for me it looks like this:

```
$whitelist = "mywifi1", "mywifi2", "mywifi3"
$netshoutput = netsh wlan show profiles | select -Skip 9
$profiles = $netshoutput.ForEach({$_.split(' ')[-1]})
$profiles.ForEach({ if ($_ -notin $whitelist) {netsh wlan delete profile name="$_"}})
```

I'm not sure that you would also need to cut exactly 9 first rows, you'd have to test that. edit: forgot to add whitelist criteria

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot and report back.